# Module not found: Can't resolve './file.scss'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass

Im new to React I am trying to use .scss to fix some issue with padding. But get this error message.

**Module not found: Can't resolve './ThreeButton.scss'**

**This is my .tsx file**

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
import ButtonGroup from '@mui/material/ButtonGroup'
import './ThreeButton.scss'

function ThreeButtton() {
 return (
   <ButtonGroup className='ThreeButton' variant="outlined" aria-label="outlined button group" >
     <Button>Leaderboard</Button>
     <Button>Overview</Button>
     <Button>Attributes</Button>
   </ButtonGroup>
 )
}

export { ThreeButtton }
```

**And this is my .scss file**

```
.ThreeButton{
    padding: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the file structure as well?

Comment: Sure, File structure is Components folder inside components is a folder called Buttons and inside buttons folder is folder called three buttons and that folder contains the .scss file and the .tsx file.